# .after don't read the var value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, delay, wait, webhooks

When I use this code even if I change the value of the "seconds" variable, it always starts the "PresaTavOff" function at 1 minute and 20 seconds, even if as a value 50 seconds or 1 second

```
function doGet() {
  var seconds = 10
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/trigger_name_1/with/key/api');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('PresaTavOff')
           .timeBased()
           .after(seconds*1000)
           .create();
}

function PresaTavOff(){
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/trigger_name_2/with/key/api');
}
```

I also tried:

`var seconds = parseInt(10)`

The code works and does everything, only the wait that doesn't respect the time I give it.
what am I wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Time isn't guaranteed AFAIK.  It's more of a attempt to do this at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [open issue for time based trigger could not fire after few seconds](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148240982), which has been acknowledged by Google and reported internally.

Whilst the documentation specifies that [time based triggers are set after x milliseconds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#afterdurationmilliseconds) my experience is that they never run exactly after the specified time. I've not seen any official documentation on limitations of the `.after()` method, but Google do say when [installing repeating time based triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) the "the time may be slightly randomized".